# Como cambiar el Font del texto de la barra de títulos en Android

Tags: android

Quisiera saber como cambiar el font de la barra de títulos, tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me gustaria obtener este, título de 2 líneas y tamaño diferente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando toobar? o solo es el label del activity?

Comment: Estoy usando la plantilla Navegation Drawer Activity del Android SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubícate en la parte del Toolbar en el .MainActivty y haz lo siguiente.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Buzón de entrada");
toolbar.setSubtitle("todas las cuentas");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

solo tendrías que agregar:

```
toolbar.setSubtitle("todas las cuentas");
```

espero que te haya servido.